# Sequelize raw SQL queries SELECT * FROM User selects the actual Database users and not my User table?

Tags: sequelize.js

When I run the following sequelize raw query:

```
const result = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM User", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

I get the following output:

```
[
    {
        "user": "postgres"
    }
]
```

That is the DB user. Why is it not looking at the User table I created in the database thus returning all the users the app created in my User table?

Comment: User is a reserved word in SQL. Hence you need to use double quotes with table name.
eg: 'SELECT * FROM "User";'.

Answer (score 0):

Edwin Babu's comment is correct.

I replaced the query with this and it now shows users from my User table.

```
const result = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM \"User\"", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```